# join two tables without losing relevant values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, data-analysis

I have two tables representing a database for customer products and its competitors' products:

`tmp_match` - from_product_id and to_product_id representing matches between customer product and competitor product respectively.

`tmp_price_history` - shows the price of each product per date.

I am trying to write a query which will list all dates from table `tmp_price_history`. For each date I want to see customer product price vs competitor product price according to product matches pairs in table `tmp_match`, regardless of whether there was a price history record **for customer product or competitor product or both**:

if both prices are available for a specific date - list them both in their columns

if there is only a record for customer product - show only customer price (and leave the competitor column blank).

if there is only record for competitor product - show competitor price in its column.

Expected result:

```
date    from_product_id to_product_id   cust_price  comp_price
1       1               11              99          95
2       1               11              98          94
1       1               12                          92
2       1               12                          91
2       2                               108
```

I tried to achieve that using this query:

```
 select cust_hist.date, from_product_id, to_product_id, cust_hist.price as cust_price,comp_hist.price as comp_price
from tmp_match as matches
       left join tmp_price_history cust_hist
         on cust_hist.product_id = matches.from_product_id
       left join tmp_price_history comp_hist
         on  comp_hist.product_id = matches.to_product_id
;
```

but it doesn't achieve my goal as can be seen in this [sql snippet](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f3a8f/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for this:

```
select distinct *
from (SELECT date,
             if(group_concat(distinct cust_price), from_product_id, null)as from_product_id,
             if(group_concat(distinct comp_price), to_product_id, null)  as to_product_id,
             group_concat(distinct cust_price)                           as cust_price,
             group_concat(distinct comp_price)                           as comp_price
      FROM (select cust_hist.date,matches.from_product_id,
                   matches.to_product_id,cust_hist.price cust_price,
                   comp_hist.price                       comp_price
            from tmp_match matches
                   inner join tmp_price_history cust_hist on matches.from_product_id = cust_hist.product_id
                   inner join tmp_price_history comp_hist on matches.to_product_id = comp_hist.product_id
            WHERE comp_hist.date = cust_hist.date
            union
            select comp_hist.date,matches.from_product_id,
                   matches.to_product_id,null as cust_price,
                   comp_hist.price               comp_price
            from tmp_price_history comp_hist
                   join tmp_match matches
                     on matches.to_product_id = comp_hist.product_id # and matches.from_product_id is null

            union
            select cust_hist.date,matches.from_product_id,
                   matches.to_product_id,
                   cust_hist.price cust_price,
                   null            comp_price
            from tmp_price_history cust_hist
                   join tmp_match matches
                     on matches.from_product_id = cust_hist.product_id # and matches.to_product_id is null

            order by DATE, from_product_id, to_product_id, cust_price, comp_price) as u
      group by date,from_product_id,to_product_id) g
```

Your idea about sql snippet was great!

Comment: this will not work when there is a record for competitor product in price_history but not for customer's product

Comment: It means that you can have a tmp_match  row that has only to_product_id and from_product_id is null ?

Comment: sorry, I did not respond to your question correctly: `tmp_match` will have only pairs of customer_product,competitor_product. but tmp_price_history can have any product that exists in tmp_match (on either side)

Comment: the current query still does not return records from tmp_price_history if there is 
 a price record only for competitor product or only for customer product. Please look at my expected result.

Comment: I have some problem with your expected result! How its possible that you have from_product_id and doesn't have cust_price? I'm talking about rows 3 and 4 in your expected result.

Comment: If from_product_id always is not null then you can not have a single competitor at all because you are defining the competitor with an one to many relation!

Comment: I came to a solution inspired by your answer, so I edited it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176024/discussion-between-max-segal-and-mehran-monster).